# Area enclosed by locus of points at fixed max distance from a closed curve

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, curves, polygons

There is a question that goes as follows:

> The locus of $P$ is the interior of an n-sided convex polygon of
>   perimeter $p$, area $\Delta$. The locus of $Q$ is all points where
>   $PQ\leq r$. Find area of locus of $Q$.

($p$, $r$, $n$ and $\Delta$ are known values)

By drawing rectangles and circular arcs around the shape, it is easy enough to prove that the answer is $rp + \pi r^2 + \Delta$.

I think we can say the same result is true for any [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve) simple closed curve, such as an ellipse. Firstly I'd like to confirm that's true.

Also I'd like to know if there is any simple way of determining the area of locus of $Q$ for a concave polygon (and if so, then what about concave curves?).

And is there any existing material online on this topic? (Ideally not too high-level, but anything's better than nothing)

Comment: P.S. If you feel the Q title is too long, feel free to edit.

Comment: I think you forgot to add $\Delta$ to your result.

Comment: @Aretino Yep. ....

Comment: I made a comment a minute ago (then deleted it) questioning your formula because I was thinking that you meant the locus of $P$ is just the boundary of the polygon (you go on to talk about "curves", so perhaps you can see where that came from). If you mean to include the interior of the polygon as well, you should make that clear. (Perhaps a convex **set**, as in the wiki article you linked?)

Comment: @NickPavlov Umm ... Okay. Does it make a difference if P is just the boundary or interior points as well? I've edited anyways, assuming it matters.

Comment: It does matter, if locus of $P$ refers to the interior, then locus of $Q$ is a solid region with area $\Delta + pr + \pi r^2$. If $P$ only refers to the boundary, then locus of $Q$ can be an annular region (i.e one has holes ) and in general have area $\le 2pr + \pi r^2$.

Comment: There's lots known along these lines. I haven't time to check out many references, but here are some : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume#Quermassintegrals , Search for _minkowski sum volume_ and follow links.

Comment: @achillehui Okay right, should have thought that. Thanks.

Comment: @EthanBolker I see. Thanks.